# Print to console Cloudfront Domain

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

Trying to print to console the Cloudfront Domain Name, but the output just doesn't seem to be stored against the service.

```
resources:
  Resources:
   CloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
     DistributionConfig:
      Origins:
        - DomainName: ${self:custom.bucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com
          Id: S3-${self:custom.siteName}
```

Outputs look like this

```
Outputs:
  CloudFrontDomainName:
   Description: CloudFront Domain Name.
   Value: {"Fn::GetAtt": ["CloudFrontDistribution", "DomainName"]}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the output just doesn't seem to be stored against the service"?

Comment: So I was expecting the CloudFrontDomainName to be stored against the service so that it appears when I run sls info. Have I misunderstood that?

Comment: try `sls info -v`

Comment: Brill that did the trick @jellycsc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to OP's feedback in the comment, `sls info -v` should do the trick